# Having Trouble while accessing classes of other sub Project in a multi-project build

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I am working on a project in my organization. It's a SpringBoot Application with **Gradle version**: 2.10. It's a multi-project build. That is, there are c sub-projects inside the main project.

> - Main Project
>
>   - SubProject A
>   - SubProject B (Common)
>   - SubProject C
>   - src (source folder of Main Project)

And here SubProject B is like the common project.

The problem I am facing here is, all classes present in "SubProject B" are accessible by other SubProjects. But classes present in "src" are not accessible by other SubProjects.

I want to know why this is happening and what changes need to do be done so that classes present in "src" are also accessible by other SubProjects?

**Note:** I am using Intellij Idea 2018.3

Thanks,

Udhav

Comment: Children accessing classes from the parent seems a bit backwards to me. If you want to share the code in the parent source directory, move it to another subproject.

Comment: @BoristheSpider so you suggest having a common subproject that will have code which is been used by other projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into many websites, found that

Children accessing classes from the parent seems a bit backwards to me. If you want to share the code in the parent source directory, move it to another subproject